# dependency diagram normalisation

Tags: database, data-modeling, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, entity-relationship

I am new to normalisation. I am using the dependency diagram to make normalisation easier for me. 
I would like to know if what I have done is correct.

Here are a list of attributes that I will try to normalise

**Attributes**

- car ID
- customer ID
- registration No
- car Model
- car Type
- customerName
- Address
- Postcode.

So the first step is to identify a determinant. In this case the registration number will be my primary key. It can identify the rest of the attributes and they all depend on it.

Then I will identify all my foreign keys. My carID and customerID are foreign keys.

For car model and number. These will depend on carID and therefore the primary key for the two mentioned will be the carID 
For customer ID the 3 attributes that depend on it are the address the postcode and customer name.

Now I will make an entity relationship based on what I have said. Car ID goes in a separate box. Customer ID goes in another box. And between them forms the link registration ID. This is how I normalised.

I am not sure if I am correct. I have provided a jpeg image of how came to my conclusion.

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLFAM.jpg)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: "identify a determinant" is strange. "PK" PKs don't matter, CKs do. FKs are irrelevant. You must find, for every pair of attribute sets or every attribute set + attribute, whether the left side determines the right side. You don't seem to be doing that. Please give your textbook name & edition & the algorithm/steps you are following & show all steps of your work. Define exactly what a "dependency diagram" tells us. Does it give a minimal cover? Are its arrows FD arrows? Is it your input or did you form it from input? Your question is not clear--what input is given & what output is wanted?

Comment: @philipxy The question is about drawing a diagram, so I would say that including an image is appropriate for this situation.

Comment: The question is about a designing a DB. But even if it were about drawing a diagram, you should use text for its content that can be given in text, and why has been clearly explained, and you have also clearly been told that your diagram is unexplained.